# Calling a Slim named route throws exception

Tags: routes, slim, named-routing

I am kinda new with Slim framework and now I have this problem with named routing... My code for the first route goes like this

```
$app->get('/admin/home', function() use ($app){

    if(!isset($_SESSION)){
        $app->render('admin/login.php', [
            'message' => 'Restricted access!'
        ]);
    }else{
        session_start();
        $app->render('admin/home.php', [
            'username' => $_SESSION['username']
        ]);
    }

})->name('/admin/home');
```

but then, when i call this route from another one like this

```
$app->post('/admin/login', function() use ($app, $conn) {
    $app->urlFor('/admin/home');
})->name('/admin/login');
```

it throws an exception "Named route already exists with name: /admin/login"

i just don't get it... is it even possible to call one route from another one? As i have seen in Slim documentation it should be... Where am i going wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Avoid naming your routes with slashes.

Instead try this:

```
$app->get('/admin/home', function() use ($app){

  // details here

})->name('admin_home');
```

Call like so:

```
$app->post('/admin/login', function() use ($app, $conn) {
  echo $app->urlFor('admin_home'); // test it
})->name('admin_login');
```

Besides, in those two examples, there is currently little advantage to those names you're giving. You're saying: 'Get me the route for `/admin/home` and it's returning `/admin/home`. If they're identical, why not use a string. Rather, the named routes are convenience methods useful for when you're doing things like returning something the url isn't totally clear about.

Simple example:

`name('user_login')` could map to `users/login`

but `name('admin_login')` might map to `admin/login`

**Routes that add clarity:**

`name('all_customers')` -> `/customers`

`name('top_n_customers)` -> `/customers/top/{count:[0-9]+}`

`name('recent_n_customers)` -> `/customers/recent/{count:[0-9]+}`

**Fancier**

```
`name('filtered_customers)` -> `/customers/{field:[a-z]+}/{value}`

// example: 
/customers/country/spain       // customers in Spain
/customers/created/2016-01-01  // New customers this year
```

Obviously, in that last example you'd have to check for valid fields and return an appropriate response if you don't support it.

NOTE: The syntax is for Slim Framework 3.0. Adjust for version 2.0 accordingly.

Comment: @Rob are you talking about a different post? This question is about Slim, not jQuery.